# duvida sobre Regex usando Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Possuo um *input*, onde quando é digitado um nome no campo, **ex.:** *João Da Silva*, ele da erro de *Regex*. No caso esse campo deve permitir letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Agora quando coloco espaço ele não salva.

Segue o código:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome" />
<p:inputText id="nome" value="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.nome}" size="40" maxlength="50" required="true">
<f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" />
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: A regex só permite letras (maiusculas e minusculas), pode adicionar um espaço na lista assim `[a-zA-Z ]` ou ainda `[a-zA-Z\s]`

Comment: não consegui ainda das duas formas que você citou.

Answer (score 1):

Ao se criar uma expressão regular, precisa-se ter em mente o que você deseja que dê match. Eu aprendi muito sobre isso com o livro de Expressões Regulares do Aurélio Verde; o [guia de expressões regulares](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/) é disponibilizado gratuitamente.

Vou dividir a construção dessa expressão regular em 2 passos:

1. Dar match em um nome sem caracteres especiais nem números (ASCII)
2. Dar match em múltiplos nomes

(Vou usar a nomenclatura do guia de regex do Aurélio Verde)

Para dar match num nome, preciso saber quais caracteres podem estar no nome. Nesse caso, todas as letras (maiúsculas e minúsculas), pelo menos uma única vez. Para dar um match nas letras, podemos usar uma *lista* que contenha essas letras: `[A-Za-z]`. Assim eu consigo garantir as letras. Para garantir um nome, uma letra precisa aparecer uma ou mais vezes, portanto precisa ser o *mais*, ficando assim agora: `[A-Za-z]+`

A interpretação que se tem ao ler essa expressão regular é: caracteres alfabéticos, em caixa alta ou baixa, que aparecem uma ou mais vezes. Isso ainda não inclui múltiplas palavras.

Para incluir outro nome, eu preciso separar o próximo nome do anterior com espaço, e ele precisa ter 1 ou mais letras que compõe um nome. Então posso dizer que os nomes subsequentes são dados pela expressão regular `[A-Za-z]+` (note o espaço antes da *lista*). Essa expressão é interpretada como um espaço seguido de um nome (conforme descrito anteriormente). Eu posso usar o *grupo* seguido de *asterisco*, pois nomes secundários podem aparecer uma ou mais vezes. Assim, `( [A-za-z]+)*` representa todos os nomes depois do primeiro nome. Para colocar um nome antes disso, obtemos `[A-za-z]+( [A-za-z]+)*`.

Uma checagem mais fraca (que permite múltiplos espaços entre nomes, começar com espaço ou ser constituído exclusivamente de espaços) é `[ A-Za-z]+`. A interpretação dessa expressão é: uma cadeia de caracteres alfabéticos, independente de caso, e de espaços em branco.